# How to customize Google Maps API marker cluster colors

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I'm using census data to plot millions (yes millions) of points on the US map. Each point represents a male or female. Therefore, I am using clustering.

However, the clusters that form have default colors that change as one zooms in or out.

Is there a way to change the color of the clusters so that all male dot clusters are one color and all female dots are another? This would also mean that I would have 2 cluster variables, one for men and one for women, but I don't want the colors for the 2 clusters to ever be the same.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation?  The clusters are configurable.

Comment: I only saw ways to alter text colors but not cluster colors